# Check if Handle (HWND) is a console

Tags: delphi

Currently i check if a HWND is a console by EnumWindows and checking the ClassName.

```
function EnumWindows(AHandle: HWND; AParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  classname: array[0.. 255] of Char;
begin
  GetClassName(AHandle, classname, 255);

  if classname = 'ConsoleWindowClass' then
  begin
    // do something
    Result := False;
  end
  else
    Result := True;
end;
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish something like this?

Would checking the Style (or/and ExStyle) be "better"?

Comment: Are you trying to find the console window associated with the current process, or another one?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError just in general. For the own current process one could use: function GetConsoleWindow: HWND; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll';

Comment: You need to define what you mean by *console* before we can tell you how to identify one.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i mean the window you get when you call AllocConsole

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AttachConsole` and `FreeConsole` do detect if other processes provide a console. One other thing to mind: there are processes with no console windows which allo `AttachConsole` - here `GetConsoleWindow` returns `0`. There is a very good explanation of this behaviour in [this github repository](https://github.com/rprichard/win32-console-docs).

*Declarations:*

```
function AttachConsole(dwProcessID: Integer): Boolean; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll';
function FreeConsole(): Boolean; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll';
function GetConsoleWindow: HWND; stdcall; external kernel32;
```

*Enumerate Processes*:

```
procedure TForm2.FindConsoleWindows(AList: TListBox);
var
  LProcHandle: THandle;
  LResult, LNext: Boolean;
  LProc: TProcessEntry32;
begin
  aList.Items.Clear;

  LProcHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  LResult := LProcHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  if LResult then
    try
      LProc.dwSize := SizeOf(LProc);
      LNext := Process32First(LProcHandle, LProc);
      while LNext do begin
        if AttachConsole(LProc.th32ProcessID) then
          try
            AList.Items.Add(IntToStr(LProc.th32ProcessID) + ' has a console ' + IntToStr(GetConsoleWindow()))
          finally
            FreeConsole();
          end;
        LNext := Process32Next(LProcHandle, LPRoc);
      end;
    finally
      CloseHandle(LProcHandle);
    end;
```

*Credits*:

- [JclSysInfo.pas](https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl/blob/master/jcl/source/common/JclSysInfo.pas) to enumerate the processes